# Blank tkinter window during long treatment

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm actually creating a gui for my python program.

The program have to read multiple data from list, using a handler class.

So, this is my `__init__`, from the `SrudbHandler` class.

```py
class SrudbHandler:

    def __init__(self, srudb):
        # var
        self.srudbfilepath = srudb
        self.esedb_obj = None
        self.liste_tables = {}
        self.id_table = {}
        # gui
        self.process_window_tk = Tk()
        self.process_window_tk.title('SRUM')
        self.process_window_tk.config(bg='#6ea5d7')
        self.process_window_tk.geometry('450x180')
        self.process_window_tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.process_window_tk.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        self.process_window_tk.columnconfigure(0, weight=30)
        self.process_window_tk.columnconfigure(1, weight=30)
        self.frame_process = Frame(self.process_window_tk, bg='#6ea5d7', pady=10, padx=5)
        self.frame_process.pack()
        label_app_resource = Label(self.frame_process, bg='#6ea5d7', text='Application :')
        label_app_timeline = Label(self.frame_process, bg='#6ea5d7', text='Timeline :')
        label_app_resource_process = Label(self.frame_process, bg='#6ea5d7', text='...')
        label_app_timeline_process = Label(self.frame_process, bg='#6ea5d7', text='...')
        self.button_next = Button(self.frame_process, text='Next')
        label_app_resource.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        label_app_timeline.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.label_app_resource_process.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.label_app_timeline_process.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.button_next.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Treatment is done later with method of the class.
During the treatment, `self.label_app_resource_process` and `self.label_app_timeline_process` text is changed from '...' to 'in progress' and then 'done'.
But...
During the treatment, my window become blank with 'not responding'.

Is this because of the long treatment ('for' loop) ?

Thanks !

Comment: loops generally block the `.mainloop` therefore the window can't update

Comment: Your code example does not include a `for/loop`